# Difference between object and value representation by example

Tags: c++, memory, language-lawyer

`N3797::3.9/4  [basic.types]` :

> The *object representation* of an object of type T is the sequence of N
>   unsigned char objects taken up by the object of type T, where N equals
>   sizeof(T). The *value representation* of an object is the set of bits
>   that hold the value of type T. For trivially copyable types, the value
>   representation is a set of bits in the object representation that
>   determines a value, which is one discrete element of an
>   implementation-defined set of values

`N3797::3.9.1  [basic.fundamental]` says:

> For narrow character types, all bits of the object representation
>   participate in the value representation.

Consider the following struct:

```
struct A
{
    char a;
    int b;
}
```

I think for `A` not all bits of the object representation participate in the value representation because of padding added by implementation. But what about others fundamentals type? 
The Standard says:
`N3797::3.9.1  [basic.fundamental]`

> For narrow character types, all bits of the object representation
>   participate in the value representation.
>   These requirements *do not* hold for other types.

I can't imagine why it doesn't hold for say `int` or `long`. What's the reason? Could you clarify?

Comment: Parity bit, for instance.

Comment: @T.C. Parity bits usually aren't visible to the software.  Tagging bits on a tagged architecture, however, are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example might be the Unisys mainframes, where an `int` has 48
bits, but only 40 participate in the *value representation* (and `INT_MAX` is 2^39-1); the
others must be 0.  I imagine that any machine with a tagged
architecture would have similar issues.

EDIT:

Just some further information: the Unisys mainframes are
probably the only remaining architectures which are really
exotic: the Unisys Libra (ex-Burroughs) have a 48 bit word, use signed
magnitude for integers, and have a tagged architecture, where
the data itself contains information concerning its type.  The
Unisys Dorado are the ex-Univac: 36 bit one's complement (but no
reserved bits for tagging) and 9 bit char's.

From what I understand, however, Unisys is phasing them out (or
has phased them out in the last year) in favor of Intel based
systems.  Once they disappear, pretty much all systems will be
2's complement, 32 or 64 bits, and all but the IBM mainframes
will use IEEE floating poing (and IBM is moving or has moved in
that direction as well).  So there won't be any motivation for
the standard to continue with special wording to support them;
in the end, in a couple of years at lesat, C/C++ could probably
follow the Java path, and impose a representation on all of its
basic data types.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour In fact, you can't implement C++ on these machines.  But that's for a different reason: they don't have any unsigned arithmetic.  In C, the solution was to simply mask the signed bit, with the results that `INT_MAX == UINT_MAX`, but because of the different formulation in the C++ standard, this isn't legal in C++.  And I think this processor is still being manufactured, for some of the Unisys ClearPath Libra systems.  (Many of these now use Intel, however.)

Comment: I'm sure 8 and 16 bit systems will still be with us for a looong time.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably meant to give the compiler headroom for optimizations on some platforms.

Consider for example a 64 bit platform where handling non-64 bit values incurs a large penalty, then it would make sense to have e.g. short only use 16 bits (value repr), but still use 64 bit storage (obj repr).

Similar rationale applies to the *Fastest minimum-width integer types* mandated by `<stdint>`. Sometimes larger types are not slower, but faster to use.

Comment: This is certainly _not_ the original motivation.  The original motivation is that on some hardware, some of the bits in an int don't participate in the value.  (And why would it make sense for a short to use only 16 bits?  On all of the word addressed machines I've worked on, `short` and `int` had exactly the same representation.)

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Although it could be, at least in theory, used to aid certain optimizations... probably on similarly exotic hardware :)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand at least one case for this is dealing with trap representations, usually on exotic architectures. This issue is covered in [N2631: Resolving the difference between C and C++ with regards to object representation of integers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2631.html). It is is very long but I will quote some sections(*The author is James Kanze, so if we are lucky maybe he will drop by and comment further*) which says (*emphasis mine*).

> In recent discussions in comp.lang.c++, it became clear that C and C++ have different requirements **concerning the object representation of integers,** and that at least one real implementation of C does not meet the C++ requirements. The purpose of this paper is to suggest wording to align the C++ standard with C.
>
> It should be noted that the issue only concerns some fairly “exotic” hardware. In this regard, it raises a somewhat larger issue

and:

> If C compatibility is desired, it seems to me that the simplest and surest way of attaining this is by incorporating the exact words from the C standard, in place of the current wording. I thus propose that we adopt the wording from the C standard, as follows

and:

> Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored value of an object has such a representation and is read by an **lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is undefined.** If such a representation is produced by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is undefined. **Such a representation is called a trap representation.**

and:

> For signed integer types [...] **Which of these applies is implementation-defined, as is whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for the first two), or with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for one's complement), is a trap representation or a normal value**. In the case of sign and magnitude and one's complement, if this representation is a normal value it is called a negative zero.