# What does a deleted pointer point to?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

```
int*a=nullptr; //NULL before C++11
a=new int(1);
delete a;
```

What does `a` point to now? Does it point to `nullptr` or does it point to the address it was pointing to before it was deleted?

Comment: It holds an invalid address. No telling what it points to

Comment: Yes, its value doesn't change.

Comment: @James: Perhaps, but the set of things you can do with that value just became empty.

Comment: @BenVoigt Agreed, its value is useless.

Comment: @JamesAdkison actually I believe to read value of that pointer is UB, so there is now way to check if value did change

Comment: But you may write `cout << *a;` and the program prints 1. You are not allowed to do that, but it may work.

Comment: @manni66 The set of things you can do with `a` excludes anything that causes undefined behavior like `cout << *a`. It's not because it compiles that you are allowed to do it.

Comment: @Slava I know dereferencing the pointer would be UB. However, just reading (e.g., `std::cout << a << "\n";`) is also UB?

Comment: @JamesAdkison See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44182938/7359094

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointers in c++ after delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182049/pointers-in-c-after-delete)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It isn't exactly the same question, but the top comment does answer mine, "undefined behavior".

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149756/is-delete-allowed-to-modify-its-parameter, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839129/are-underlying-bytes-of-an-object-allowed-to-change-if-the-value-is-not-changed. The conclusion of these answers is the standard is not clear on this subject (as far as I understand).

Comment: And there is one implementation which **changes** pointer value after delete: visual studio with the option `/sdl`.

Comment: "Does it point to nullptr" Nothing can point *to* `nullptr`. `nullptr` is a constant, like `42` or `'a'`. It has no address. A pointer can *be* a null pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (6.7 Storage duration)

> 4 When the end of the duration of a region of storage is reached, the
>   values of all pointers representing the address of any part of that
>   region of storage **become invalid pointer values** (6.9.2).
>   Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid
>   pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior. Any
>   other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined
>   behavior.

So after this expression statement

```
delete a;
```

the value of the pointer `a` is not changed but has became invalid. Neither object exists at this address.

Comment: “the value of the pointer a is not changed”. That’s not what that snippet says. It describes what’s undefined and then states that everything else is *implementation-defined*. That includes reading the pointer’s value. For example it would be perfectly compliant for a compiler to change the value of all deleted pointers to nullptr.

Comment: @besc: are you sure? `nullptr` is not an invalid pointer value.

Comment: @geza nullptr did not point to an object while we are speaking about pointers that pointed to objects. So I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: besc said that a compiler could change the pointer value to nullptr. But the standard says that the pointer value becomes invalid pointer value. And a `nullptr` is clearly not an invalid pointer value.

Comment: What I mean is that you cannot make any assumptions about which value the pointer variable contains after the delete without speaking about a specific (version of a) compiler. The standard says that – excluding the UB cases – any access to that pointer’s value has implementation-defined behaviour. That means the behaviour is entirely up to the compiler vendor, but they must document it. Setting to nullptr was just a quick example of what a vendor could decide. I’m not saying that’s reasonable or even technically possible. I’m just saying the standard explicitly allows things like that.

Comment: @besc, but if the implementation chooses nullptr, then it is not an invalid pointer value. So, in a way, it violates the standard, which says that the pointer value becomes an invalid pointer value.

Comment: @geza I’d have to read the standard in a bit more detail to be sure. How I understand “invalid pointer value” is that this pointer does not point to a valid object anymore, not that the value stored in the pointer variable itself becomes invalid somehow. Provided nobody changed it, essentially it’s still just an integer number that represents a memory address.

Comment: @besc: maybe :) I'm not nitpicking. I've asked a similar question before (check the comments I've made at the question), and unfortunately, it seems that a clear answer cannot be derived from the standard.

Comment: @besc - When we delete a large memory object, the memory manager might return it to the operating system which unmaps the address range. If so, the "integer number" no longer represents a memory address. On some hardware, loading an unmapped value into an address register will trap.

Comment: @BoPersson: which CPU works like this? Does it have a C++11 compiler? I ask this because of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119928/c11-on-exotic-hardware).

Comment: @geza - I was thinking of the 68000 with dedicated address registers, and the segment registers present in 32-bit x86 (both of which you already have in an answer). It is "just" that nobody cared to support far pointers in a 32-bit OS, but the hardware is still there. Can a language standard forbid the use of those features?

Comment: @BoPersson, why not, if they don't add anything useful. As I see, we are fine without segment register support (we needed them in the 16-bit era, but currently they're not very useful in a 32/64-bit C++ program). And maybe there is no C++11 compiler for 68000 or with segment register support at all. Thanks for the info on 68000 (I didn't programmed it).

Comment: For practical purposes I think it’s safe to say that after the object behind a pointer is deleted there are only two sensible things to do with that pointer variable. Re-assign it or let it go out of scope and be cleaned up. If you do anything else, you shall burn in code review! ;) From the language-lawyer perspective I don’t see the ambiguity. To do anything with the “invalid pointer value” there is no way around reading it, which falls under “any other use” and is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 6):

A few other answers incorrectly say "the value doesn't change". However it does:  before the deletion it was valid, and after the deletion it is invalid; this is a change.

Further, the representation of the value may change too. For example the implementation could set `a` to be null, or some pattern that the debugger will recognize to help with detecting invalid uses of variables.

Comment: _A few other answers incorrectly say "the value doesn't change"_ I've downvoted that answers.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't point to anything. There is nothing useful you can do with its value now.

Answer (score 4):

Don't confuse the pointer's value with what it points *to*.  After the delete, the pointer's value is unchanged.  It isn't set to `nullptr` or anything like that.  The thing it points *to* is undefined.  All to often, it ends up pointing to exactly what it did before, which leads to all manner of interesting bugs.

Comment: Actually does language specify if value is changed or not? There is no way to check if it changed

Comment: *"After the delete, the pointer's value is unchanged."* That's not guaranteed.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Would you agree that all of the following guarantee the pointer `a`'s value is unchanged? `delete +a;`  `delete a+0;`  `delete ((int*)a);`  `auto c = a; delete c;`

Comment: afaik implementations are allow to set the pointer to `nullptr` during `delete`,

Comment: @tobi303: the argument to delete may be a rvalue expression, so it might not be modifieable at all

Comment: @tobi303: It is certainly difficult to detect whether it has changed, without introducing undefined behavior.  I believe however that one could safely `memcpy` the pointer value (not dereferenced!) to a byte buffer of sufficient size.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think so, but how would you check that? Copy its object representation to a `char[]` and compare that?

Comment: @AndreasH. It is possible that the value does not change, but this answer states something different: "After the delete, the pointer's value is unchanged" which is: it cannot change

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Yes, that's the only legal operation I can think of, on a pointer holding an invalid value.

Comment: @BenVoigt I have to admit that I am a little bit confused after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44182938/4117728). I am starting to believe that there a millions of programs with UB out there and I am just happy that I didnt use any `delete` since ages

Comment: @tobi303 I'm certain that there are millions of programs with UB out there.

Comment: @Slava: actually, there may be a way. As far as I know, it depends on how one interprets the standard. You're maybe able to check the change with `memcpy`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149756/is-delete-allowed-to-modify-its-parameter